# How can this function be considered to have a saddle node bifurcation?

Tags: general-topology, functions, dynamical-systems, bifurcation

Say I have the function $f(x,\mu) = (1 + \mu)x − x^2 − 0.1$. By definition a Saddle Node bifurcation occurs if:

- $f_{\mu_0}(0) = 0$
- $f'_{\mu_0}(0) = 1$
- $f''_{\mu_0}(0) \neq 0$
- $\frac{\delta f_\mu}{\delta \mu}|_{(x,\mu)=(0,\mu_0)} \neq 0$

I can see how the bifurcation points existence can be shown by proving the fixed points come into existence at a certain value of $\mu$. ie. when $\frac{1}{2} (\mu \pm \sqrt{\mu^2 -0.4})=0$ or when $\mu = \pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}$. That is clear, what I am struggling with is maybe the understanding of the criteria.

I cannot see how bullet point number one is satisfied, surely $f_{\mu_0}(0) = 0.1$ ? I'm probably not understanding the definitions correctly, any help would be appreciated  - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you misunderstanding comes from the convention that in theory bifurcation state is usually placed at origin. It always can be done by simple shift of coordinates and it's usually done for the sake of having less ambiguous notation (as far as I understand that). So if you want to check whether it is a saddle-node bifurcation or not, you just have to shift your coordinate system such that steady state will appear at $0$ or reformulate conditions the following way.

If $\mu_0$ is a critical value of parameter and $x_{\mu_0}$ is the coordinate of appearing fixed point, then conditions should be rewritten as:

- $f_{\mu_0}(x_{\mu_0}) = x_{\mu_0}$
- $f'_{\mu_0}(x_{\mu_0}) = 1$
- $f''_{\mu_0}(x_{\mu_0}) \neq 0$
- $\frac{\delta f_\mu}{\delta \mu}|_{(x,\mu)=(x_{\mu_0},\mu_0)} \neq 0$

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks alot.

Comment: Sorry maybe its because I'm overtired but I am still struggling to arrive at the result of the first bullet point. If $\mu_0 = \frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}$ then $x_{\mu_0} = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$ which when put into the equation gives: $-(1 + 2/\sqrt{10}) / \sqrt{10} - 0.1 -0.1 \neq 0$ ... ?

Comment: I think that might be just a typo in your calculations. My formula for roots of this quadratic equation is different than yours: I have discriminant equal to $(1+\mu)^2 - 0.4$ and from this critical values of $\mu$ are $1 \pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}$, not $\pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}$ as you've written.

Comment: $\pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}$ is given in the question. If you have a fixed point, then $(1+\mu)x−x^2−0.1 = x \Rightarrow \mu x−x^2−0.1 = 0 \Rightarrow x = \frac{1}{2} (\mu \pm \sqrt{\mu^2−0.4})$ hence bifurcation point when $\mu = \pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}$ If you find the values of x directly from the function, you are not getting the fixed points are you? And are we not interested in when a stable and then unstable fixed point merge and vanish , as by the definition of a saddle node bifurcation? You probably are right, but just want to be certain...

Comment: Sorry then, abuse of notation happened. I was talking about continuous dynamical systems, but I've corrected conditions. I still think that you have a typo: I've checked the critical case $\mu^2 = 0.4$, everything is OK.

Comment: With your corrected conditions, it now works. Thanks for your answer!